# Join AWS cluster members of Hazelcast from outside

Tags: amazon-web-services, hazelcast

I have multiple applications running in EC2, all of them have Hazelcast as a server and all of them are recognized as members and create a cluster.

Now I have an application running in EKS which has Hazelcast as a server inside as well. My goal is for a member from EKS could join members in EC2 and make a cluster of them because all applications share the same cache.

What I did: added an aws join configuration to the EKS application and I see It could find out possible members but could not connect, from logs:

`Sending master question to 'internal aws IP of member'`, after a few tries it gives up trying to connect and create its own cluster with the standalone master member.

If it is possible to join members in AWS, what I should change, make members from AWS accessible as TCP-IP, or should update some configuration?
And I believe after the master question, it should respond to EKS member which trying to join, so EKS member won't be accessible?